# I am investigating the connectivity of a graph. Why am i getting segmentation fault: 11?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

```
     void checkconnections(int matrix[N][N], int connected[N], int j)
     {
     int i;


     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
         if(matrix[i][j]>0)
         {
              connected[i]=1;
              j=i;
              checkconnections(matrix, connected, j);
         }
     }
```

}

I have a connectivity matrix in which values are randomly generated. If they are connected, the value is set to one if not the value is set to 0. N is defined in the header.

Comment: what's your initial call to this function?

Comment: checkconnections(matrix, connected, j);

Comment: I mean, their values esp. j. i looks fine in the function so the only part that can violate NxN boundary I can think of is j.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a segmentation fault because infinite recursion is going to result and the stack will overflow.

Just work through what happens if both `matrix[4][5]` and `matrix[5][4]`, e.g., are non-zero.